# Finding a range and then implementing it in another formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]
I am trying to use a variable range based on a pre-defined criteria. In my case I would like to find the range of the “AUD” cells in the table. I managed to get the beginning of the range thanks to:

```
=ADDRESS(1;MATCH("AUD";1:1;0))
```

And then I found the end of the range using a slightly modified above formula:

```
=ADDRESS(1;(MATCH("AUD";1:1;0)+(COUNTIF(1:1;"AUD"))-1))
```

Then I simply combined the results with the following formula:

```
=(B4&":"&C4)
```

And the achieved result was:

```
$B$1:$D$1
```

However, I am having difficulties implementing this result inside formulas in which range must be defined, which brings me to my following questions:

1. Is such kind of implementation possible in EXCEL, I suspect that the result is considered as a simple text and not actually a cell reference? Is there a way I can change that?
2. One step further, if we trim (for example from $B$1 to just $B) can we still make the formula working?
3. Due to the fact that to save space I will probably write all the above formulas inside one formula and I expect this formula to become huge, would it be possible to create a VBA public function which can store the range in a variable and then just refer this variable to the formula - for example, SUMIF("=audRefCell()";"AUD";2:2).

I would like to thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. *Is such kind of implementation possible in EXCEL, I suspect that the result is considered as a simple text and not actually a cell reference? Is there a way I can change that?* Yes, check function INDIRECT https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Comment: The answer to your question is that all is probably possible, but can you explain more about your end goal. What do you want to do with that range? Would you use it to calculate the amount? Using functions as `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT` (to return a working range) would be volatile and there are little examples I've seen that really require any such function per se.

Comment: The last point of your question really makes me wonder. A simple `SUMIF` formula does the job just fine, e.g: `SUMIF(1:1,"AUD",2:2)`. The way you want to use a formula is not even going to return the correct result as the ranges in your formula would differ.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - I have tried by when I type '=INDIRECT((ADDRESS(1;MATCH("AUD";1:1;0)))&":"&(ADDRESS(1;(MATCH("AUD";1:1;0)+(COUNTIF(1:1;"AUD"))-1)));TRUE)' I am getting an error. Could you please hint what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My example is a simplified version of what I have to deal with. I have a random number of columns in total of 30 different currencies where one column in this example is represented by 20 with different information that I need to filter. I am worried that with a "SUMIFS" method it will be quite slow to calculate such a great amount of cells. I think it will be easier if we find the range and use "SUMIFS" for calculations for that range specifically instead of filter through 20000 columns with getting 99.9 false results due to unmatched currency type.

Comment: Would the columns always be contiguous? Also for your information the correct use of `INDIRECT` would be `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS....` you need to do that twice in your formula. When you say you worry about the speed of your formula and workbook, than surely volatile functions would NOT fit that picture.

Comment: @JvdV, Yes, at least that from the exercise is simplified. 

I have tried to separate the beginning formula from the end one and wrap both of them in a indirect formula and it worked. The result was "AUDAUD" which is exactly what it should have displayed. However, when I pasted the formula in a SUMIF formula it got me that this method is volatile and automatically it returned an error.

Comment: ... continuing my comment here...

I am fully aware of that. I have tried to do it with "SUMIFS" when taking ranges of whole rows but when you have 22 formulas of that type just in one represented cell in my simplified example is not a very efficient way. 

My best bet if it possible to create a public function with VBA and then use variables that have already been calculated on start up to refer the range from there in a sumif. That way you will downgrade the amount of calculation needed but unfortunately, I am not that experienced with VBA.

Comment: VBA can certainly achieve you are after but I think you are over-complicating what you tried to achieve. If it is simply summing by different criteria over different ranges, excel formula can do the job. You need to break down your questions as for now no one knows what exactly you are trying to do with finding the ranges. If it is for **SUMIF** only, there is no need to find the range for AUD as explained by @JvdV besides the range you find is not matching to the range you are trying to sum so it will of course return an error...